# Is there a weak/soft bidirectional Map in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, weak-references, bimap

I would like a "symbol alphabet" to have a bi-directional map with weak/soft references. Something like an Apache's Common `BidiMap` (or Guava's `BiMap`) with a `WeakMap`-like interface.

A solution would be to use `BiMap<WeakReference<K>,V>` and once in a while clean-up entries, but it's not optimal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doable, but your proposed solution isn't really a solution at all, because you can't look up a `K` in a map of `WeakReference<K>`.

Comment: If you filed a feature request with Guava with more explanation of why you actually want such a structure, that might also help.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the 'BiMap<WeakReference<K>,V>'. I dropped that solution. I have now implemented something on the 'AbstractDualBidiMap' of Apache commons (with two 'ReferenceMaps') but I am still testing it to see if it works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're up for building a custom implementation, almost certainly the right way to do it will be to build your own custom hash table and maintain a `ReferenceQueue` that's used to track removals.